# How would I ask if they want to calculate again?

Tags: python, loops

This is what I have so far but I can't seem to get a code to work that let's me ask at the end of the calculation if they would like to make another calculation again.

```
#_function definitions_________________________________________________________________________________________________

def validate_pay_rate(pay_rate):
    while pay_rate < 7.5 or pay_rate > 18.25:
        print ("\nERROR: You entered an invalid pay rate...")
        pay_rate = float(input("Enter employee's pay rate: $"))
    else:
        return pay_rate

def validate_hours_worked(hours_worked):
    while hours_worked <= 0 or hours_worked > 40:
        print ("\nERROR: You entered an invalid amount of work hours...")
        hours_worked = float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
    else:
        return hours_worked

def calculate_gross_pay(pay_rate, hours_worked):
    print("Gross Pay = $" + "%.2f" % float(pay_rate * hours_worked))



#_main_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
pay_rate = float(input("Enter employee's pay rate: $"))
validate_pay_rate(pay_rate)
hours_worked = float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
validate_hours_worked(hours_worked)
calculate_gross_pay(pay_rate, hours_worked)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the issue you're encountering? Also, I believe those else statements in the functions are unnecessary.

Comment: I am very new to python and this is for class. I need to create a loop for this program that at the end of the program it ask if you would like to pretty much use the program again to calculate another payroll. I can't seem to get it working no matter how hard I try and I honestly really don't know what I am doing. I have this but it just repeats its self over again and does not repeat the whole program and I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: while True:
    a = input("Another? Yes or No?")
    if a=="yes":
        main()
        continue
    elif a=="no":
        break
    else:
        print("End")

Comment: Hmm, this question might be of use here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/11301900.

Comment: As an aside, it's probably best to have the functions return values, rather than printing directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understod you correctly this is what you wanted.

```
#main_____________________________________________________________________________
while True:
    pay_rate = float(input("Enter employee's pay rate: $"))
    validate_pay_rate(pay_rate)
    hours_worked = float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
    validate_hours_worked(hours_worked)
    calculate_gross_pay(pay_rate, hours_worked)
    continue_ = input("Do you want to do this again? Y/N: ")
    if continue_ == "n" or continue_ == "N":
        break
    else:
        print() # Just to get a space between each input
```

Comment: Instead of the `print()`, you could just add a newline at the start of the first `input()`. It would probably be cleaner.

Comment: You can't add `\n` to a `input()`, if this was not what you meant please tell me what you meant. @AMC

Comment: I meant change the start of the loop from  `float(input(“Enter...”))` to `float(input(“\nEnter...”))`.

Comment: I tried that but nothing happend in pycharm, so i thought it coulden't be done.

Comment: That’s really strange, I’ll try it myself and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Put an loop around the main block. Something like this would work.
You should of course do something nicer for the input but thats the minimal version.

```py
#_main_________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
calculated = False
while not calculated or input("Redoo or something else (type y/n)") == "y":
    pay_rate = float(input("Enter employee's pay rate: $"))
    validate_pay_rate(pay_rate)
    hours_worked = float(input("Enter hours worked: "))
    validate_hours_worked(hours_worked)
    calculate_gross_pay(pay_rate, hours_worked)
    calculated = True
```